# Predicting new instance with missing predictor

Tags: machine-learning, prediction

I have a (probably stupid) question about predicting a new instance with a missing predictor(s).

I am given a data. Let's say I preprocess, clean data and as a result, let's say, 10 predictors left. Then, I train my model on a resulting data, so I am ready to use model to predict.

Now, what should I do if I want to predict a new instance which 1 or 2 predictors are missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two reasonable solutions.

(1) Average the output over the possible values of the missing variable or variables, conditional on the values of the non-missing variables. That is, compute a weighted average of the output prediction(missing, non-missing) for each possible value of missing, weighted by the probability of missing given non-missing. This is essentially a variety of what's called "multiple imputation" in the literature.

The first thing to try is to just weight by the unconditional distribution of missing. If that seems too complicated, a very rough approximation is to substitute the mean value of missing into the prediction.

(2) Build a model for each combination variables. If you have n variables, this means building 2^n variables. If n = 10, 1024 models is not a big deal these days. Then if you are missing some variables, just use the model for the ones that are present.

By the way, you might get more interest in this question at stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I got the second one immediately. But it took me a little while to understand the first one. I really appreciate Robert. I took several machine learning courses, and read books, but never seen such a problem and answer to it. Can you suggest me any book or course which covers challenges in ML and its solutions in industry?

Comment: Well, (1) is a Bayesian approach. As for books, you could take a look at "Pattern Recognition and Neural Networks" by Brian Ripley, or "Elements of Statistical Learning" by Hastie, Tibshirani, and Friedman. Both books have a Bayesian slant and in general I think you'll find a Bayesian approach useful.

Comment: I really appreciate. I will definitely consider the books you mentioned.